# Cannot change boot menu on ZFS filesystem

Tags: grub2, zfs

I have Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS and ZFS partitions.
I'm using Grub Customizer, however boot menu configuration which I can see in Grub Customization is different from menu which I can see during start up, looks like grub customizer doesn't cooperate with ZFS filesystem. I noticed also that if I open Disk application then I can see that bpool is Unknown (zfs_member 5000) — Not Mounted

[image]

but when I use **sudo zpool status -v** then it shows that everything is fine.

[image]

Anyone had this problem and know how to fix it?